# Python lxml - get index of tag's text

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml-file with a format similar to docx, i.e.:

```
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>BIG_TEXT</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I need to get an index of `BIG_TEXT` in source xml, like:

```
from lxml import etree
text = open('/devel/tmp/doc2/word/document.xml', 'r').read()

root = etree.XML(text)

start = 0
for e in root.iter("*"):
    if e.text:
        offset = text.index(e.text, start)
        l = len(e.text)
        print 'Text "%s" at offset %s and len=%s' % (e.text, offset, l)
        start = offset + l
```

I can start a new search from position of current `index` + `len(text)`, but is there another way? Element may have one character, `w` for example. It will find index of `w`, but not index of tag text `w`.

Comment: What value do you expect the index to have? Line number + column? Byte offset? What have you tried so far, but didn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for a similar solution (indexing nodes in a big xml file for fast lookup).

- AFAIK, `lxml` only offers sourceline, which is insufficient. Cf [API](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) : `Original line number as found by the parser or None if unknown.`
- But `expat` provides the exact offset in the file : [CurrentByteIndex](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.xmlparser.CurrentByteIndex).

  - Fetched from `start_element` handler, it returns tag's start (ie `'<'`) offset.
  - Fetched from `char_data` handler, it returns data's start (ie `'B'` in your example) offset.

Example :

```
import xml.parsers.expat

# handler functions for parser events, and housekeeping.
class handler :
   def __init__(self, current_parser) :
      #tag of interest
      self.TARGET_TAG = "w:t"

      #set up parser
      self.parser = current_parser
      self.parser.StartElementHandler  = self.start_element
      self.parser.EndElementHandler    = self.end_element
      self.parser.CharacterDataHandler = self.char_data

      self.target_tag_met = False
      self.index = None

   def start_element(self, name, attrs):
      self.target_tag_met = (name == self.TARGET_TAG)

   def end_element(self, name) :
      self.target_tag_met = False

   def char_data(self, data):
      if self.target_tag_met :
         self.index = self.parser.CurrentByteIndex

#open file in binary mode for robuster byte offsets.
xmlFile = open("so_test.xml", 'rb')

p = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()
h = handler(p)

p.ParseFile(xmlFile)
print (h.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the character indices for all elements, attributes, tags, text, etc. in valid XML document using [Pawpaw](https://github.com/rlayers/pawpaw):

**Code:**

```
import sys
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pawpaw import xml
text = """<doc xmlns:w="foo.goo">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:sz w:val="36"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>BIG_TEXT</w:t>
    </w:r>
</doc>"""
root = ET.fromstring(text, parser=xml.XmlParser())
prefix_map = xml.XmlHelper.get_prefix_map(root)
e = root.find('.//w:t', namespaces=prefix_map)
ito = e.ito.find('**[d:text]')
print(f'{ito:%span}')
```

**Output:**

```
(144, 152)
```