# How to find distance between 2 elements in html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The goal is to find the distance between 2 tags, e.g. the first external a href attribute and the title tag, using BeautifulSoup.

```
html = '<title>stackoverflow</title><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">test</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
ext_link = soup.find('a',href=re.compile("^https?:",re.IGNORECASE))
title = soup.title
dist = abs_distance_between_tags(ext_link,title)
print dist
30
```

How would I do this without using regex?

Note that the order of the tags maybe different, and there maybe more than one match (although we only are taking the first using find() ).

I could not find a method in BeautifulSoup that returns the locations/positions in the html of the matches.

Comment: What type of "distance"? Number of tags between them? Depends on how exactly you want to count them. Pixels on the screen? Depends on the browser you are targeting. Something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the string character count between them, in the example the position of the s in stackoverflow to the h in https.

Comment: I don't understand your aversion to regex. You could `ext_link = soup.find(lambda x: x.name == "a" and (x["href"].startswith("http:") or x["href"].startswith("https:")))`, but this is uglier and less flexible.

Comment: Usually parsing HTML/XML with a regex is awful, but in this case, it might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, it does not seem like you can get the exact character position of an element in BeautifulSoup.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12463426/25097) can help you along:

> AFAIK, lxml only offers sourceline, which is insufficient. Cf [API](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html): `Original line number as found by the parser or None if unknown.`
>
> But expat provides the exact offset in the file : CurrentByteIndex.
>
> - Fetched from start_element handler, it returns tag's start (ie '<') offset.
> - Fetched from char_data handler, it returns data's start (ie 'B' in your example) offset.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup 4 now supports `Tag.sourceline` and `Tag.sourcepos`.

Reference: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#line-numbers